# How do you link radio buttons with text fields in rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, radio-button

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :Owner %><br>
  <%= f.radio_button :owner, "Option1" %>
  <%= f.label :owner, "Option1" %><br>
  <%= f.radio_button :owner, "Option2" %>
  <%= f.label :owner, "Option2" %><br>
  <%= f.radio_button :owner, value: ""} %>
  <%= f.text_field :owner %>
</div>
```

So I have a couple of options for the radio buttons and for the last one I wanted to leave it open with a text field. Basically, I want the form to select the last radio button when the user starts typing in the text field. Is there a way to link the two things? I know in html you can just throw the text field code within the radio_button code but I don't think this is possible in rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using jquery. You just need to write `onChange` function for the text field and in that function you can set the last radio input to `checked`
Considering your view:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :Owner %><br>
  <%= f.radio_button :owner, "Option1" %>
  <%= f.label :owner, "Option1" %><br>
  <%= f.radio_button :owner, "Option2" %>
  <%= f.label :owner, "Option2" %><br>
  <%= f.radio_button :owner, value: "", :class => "custom" %>
  <%= f.text_field :owner, :class => "user-defined" %>
</div>
```

The jquery function for this would be:

```
$(".user-defined").change(function(){
  if($(this).val()){
    $(".custom").prop('checked', true);
  }
  else{
    $(".custom").prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

This is not tested but i hope it gives you the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, it's telling me I need 15 reputation points in order to upvote. But I will do so once I am able to :)